# multiple instances of chrome app

Tags: google-chrome-app, multiple-instances

Chrome app newbie here...

One of the first things I am trying to figure out is how to have multiple instances of a chrome app running at the same time.

Googling reveals numerous people asking how to 'prevent' multiple instances, and refer to adding a "singleton: true" in the launcher .js file.  My apps are singleton already, and adding "singleton: false" seems to have no effect.  Other references suggest that if an "id" is present, it will be forced as singleton.  However, removing the id seems to have no effect for me, either.

Experimenting with the simple [helloworld tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app), which has neither an id: or singleton:, even this app only runs as a singleton.
I am launching the app with "google --load-and-launch-app=/home/me/helloworld".  If I run that command multiple times, it simply brings the original app to the front and center.

If someone can explain how to make the tutorial run multiple instances, then hopefully I can apply that to the larger pre-existing project I'm starting to look at.

Comment: Do you need true separate instances, or just several identical windows?

Comment: True separate instances is the goal.  For example, if my app was an image viewer, I'd want to view different images in each simultaneously.

Comment: That still sounds like something a single app with multiple windows can handle.

Comment: Ok, maybe I misunderstood what you meant by "identical".  I thought you meant identical contents as well.  Ok, so how would you modify the helloworld to have multiple windows (single instance), such that each click of the app icon, or each launch via the command line as I posted, would result in a new window?

Comment: For me, simply removing the `id` works. Every click on the app in `chrome://apps` launches a new window. Odd that it doesn't for you - can you post your background script?